# Unable to access Office.context.mailbox.item when accessing a shared Mailbox

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

Version Affected:

- OfficeJS 1.1.38
- Mac Outlook Version: 16.34 (20020900)

Note: Accessing `Office.context.mailbox.item.body` was working for shared inbox prior to the Mac Outlook Version update.

We are experiencing an issue with accessing a ***Shared Mailbox***'s (Works with individual mail box)

- `Office.context.mailbox.item.body`

Following calls returns a null object:

```
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", function(result) {
      var body_html = result.value;
      console.log('HTML', body_html);
    });
```